# EventBus throws No public method onEvent(Message message) when I register

Tags: android, greenrobot-eventbus

I have this pretty straight forward declaration

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onStop();
}

public void onEventMainThread(RefreshMessage message){
    ToastUtils.showLongToast(getActivity(), message.getRefresh() ? "ok":"false");
}
```

I don't know why it still throws

> has no public methods called onEvent

Please let me know if I missed something. Also my fragment extends an AbstractClass

Comment: `build->clean` does't help?

Comment: nope, doesn't help. it's a runtime error btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's taking me so long to debug the error, I implemented my own simple EventBus using a singleton

```
public class EventBusMainThread {
private static EventBusMainThread selfInstance;

private List<EventBusSubscriber> subscribers;

public EventBusMainThread() {
    this.subscribers = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
}

public static EventBusMainThread getInstance(){
    if(selfInstance == null)
        selfInstance = new EventBusMainThread();
    return selfInstance;
}

public synchronized void register(EventBusSubscriber subscriber){
    subscribers.add(subscriber);
}

public synchronized void unregister(EventBusSubscriber subscriber){
    subscribers.remove(subscriber);
}

public void post(Object message){
    for(EventBusSubscriber subscriber : subscribers){
        subscriber.onEvent(message);
    }
}}
```